# Inserting HTML with PHP does not work on JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, html, insert

When inserting HTML code with PHP the `<script>` brackets are not being interpreted though the `<p>` tag works just fine.

This is the PHP excerpt:

```
echo "<p>Test</p><script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('signalframe1').src = 'http://live.telldus.com/device/switch?mode=on&id=101443';</script>";
```

Is my syntax wrong or is later inserted JavaScript just not being executed?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does not work? Context? More infos?

Comment: so what is the actual output, i would expect this to work ..?

Comment: Is the `signalframe1` element (I'm guessing an `<iframe>`) defined above in the outputted HTML code? If not, `document.getElementById('signalframe1')` will return empty.

Comment: The inserted JavaScript is supposed to change the source of the iframe to the given URL. When looking into the source code in the browser the <div> where the code is supposed to go is empty. The "p" tag though is being interpreted and displayed correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, the iframe tag is defined above the outputted code.

Answer (score 1):

your javascript does not know about the **signalframe1** element, because this runtime (later added) javascript only knows about the html added with this php script, for that you can add one copy of the script in the html page so that its present when the html is loaded, and the other in php if you need bcz later if you want to add some html there in the php and that should work on that html doc. hope it will help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, you were right! I just inserted a whole new iframe with the URL as source. That did the trick.